# Inheritance: Set Values of Abstract Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dictionary

I am currently working on a small project that includes an abstract baseclass of sorts, which defines some methods that require a dictionary. Yet the dicitionary is individual for each derived class.

Therefore I defined the dictionary in my baseclass as follows:

```
abstract internal Dictionary<string, column> columnNames { get; }
```

and in each inheriting class I set that dicitonary like so:

```
internal override Dictionary<string, column> columnNames
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, column>{
                {"partID", new column{ name = "ID", show = false, type = typeof(int)}},//false
                {"partName", new column{ name = "Name", show = true, type = typeof(string)}}
            };
        }
    }
```

Now if I want to change properties of the dicitonary I tried the following:

```
columnNames["partID"].show = true;
```

Which does not work. There is no exception, the value in the dicitionary simply does not chance.

I also wrote a set-Function within my base-class:

```
public void setDictEntry(string key, column value)
    {
        columnNames[key] = value;
    }
```

But it still did not work. I was wondering: Is it because my dictionary does not have a `set`  property?

For completion, here the definition of the column class:

```
class column
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool show { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public System.Type type { get; set; }
}
```

As always, sorry for my bad english and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it doesn't change - you're always returning a different `Dictonary`! You'll have to return an existing dictionary (for example, by storing the dictionary in a field) to have it (effectively) mutable.

```
Dictionary<string, column> _columnNames = 
        new Dictionary<string, column>{
            {"partID", new column{ name = "ID", show = false, type = typeof(int)}},//false
            {"partName", new column{ name = "Name", show = true, type = typeof(string)}}
        };

internal override Dictionary<string, column> columnNames
{
    get
    {
        return _columnNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I am finally beginning to start to grasp how properties work ...

Comment: @Jonas The important point is that properties have no hidden magic whatsoever - they're just methods (get and/or set), nothing else. The only sugar is that instead of using e.g. `GetColumnNames` and `SetColumnNames` explicitly, you can use `var x = ColumnNames` and `ColumnNames = x`. In fact, the C# compiler explicitly emits the method `get_ColumnNames` for you :)